# Can localstack support an S3 snapshot repository for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, localstack

I am using [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) to mock various AWS services for testing my software. I am trying to write some code that can create an elasticsearch snapshot repository and then create snapshots of my elasticsearch indicies in s3. When I try to test this against my localstack instance I get the following error:

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=repository_exception, reason=[test] repository type [s3] does not exist]], Type[org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException] message[Elasticsearch exception [type=repository_exception, reason=[test] repository type [s3] does not exist]
```

Can localstack be configured to support this? If so can you provide instructions on how to do so?

Thank you!